# background gradient в div

Tags: html, css, linear-gradient

У меня есть картинка с градиентом на заднем фоне. Она находится в блоке div, в котором background справа должен быть продолжением градиента картинки. Попробовал сделать но на фоне все равно видно отличие в цветах.
[image: Pribor]

```
 <div class="banner">
      <img src="../images/pribor.jpg">
    </div>
    .banner {
      width: 100%;
      display: flex;
      background: linear-gradient(14deg, rgba(87,114,181,1) 0%, rgba(53,151,222,1) 94%);
    }
```

Comment: уберите градиент с картинки, оставьте там только девайсы на прозрачном фоне

Comment: Добавьте после linear-gradient() `no-repeat`

Comment: http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-repeat

Comment: @Voprositel добавил. но все равно виден зазор.

Comment: Тонкий кусок фона отрежте справа от картинки и размножте под картинкой `repeat-x`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы добавили лишние 14 градусов в наклоне фона и не попали в точки остановки цветов.

Но лучше, конечно использовать png без фона (или даже webp).

```css
img {
  height: 400px;
  display: block;
}

.container {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, #5c73af 16%, #5099db 91%);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YmQD.png">

</div>
```